# Transpose data using an identifier

Tags: r, bash, bioinformatics, blast

I have text file ([blast software output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST)) with a single column and about 40,000 rows, which looks as below.

Essentially, I would like to use R or terminal to convert this to multiple columns with first columns containing Query name and other columns containing query hits with each hit appended to a new column

Input is this:

```
Query1
result1
result2
result3

Query2
result1
result2
result3
result4
result5   

Query3
result1
result2
result3
result4
```

Expected output

```
Query1 result1 result2 result3 
Query2 result1 result2 result3 result4 result5
Query3 result1 result2 result3 result4
```

Comment: What is *blast output*? What format -txt? An R type -vector, list, dataframe?

Comment: Sorry, blast part is not important, its a program to identify proteins from a database. The output is a text file with a single column and ~40,000 rows as shown above. I just want to tabulate different proteins identified for a single query. I don't necessarily have to use R but would be helpful to know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider running `readLines()` to read the text file line by line, building a large list of character vectors. Below also iteratively maps the section header (i.e. *Query1*, *Query2*) to names of the individual character vectors:

```
con <- file("/path/to/text/file.txt", open="r")

datalist <-  c()
while (length(line <- readLines(con, n=1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {

  if (grepl("Query", line)==TRUE){
    query <- c()                                              # RESET VECTOR
    qName <- line                                             # CAPTURE QUERY NAME
  }
  else if (grepl("([A-Za-z])", line)==TRUE){
    query <- c(query, line)                                   # APPEND LINE TO VECTOR
  }
  else if (line == ""){
    datalist <- c(datalist, setNames(list(query), qName))     # APPEND NAMED VECTOR TO LIST
  }
}

datalist <- c(datalist, setNames(list(query), qName))         # REMAINING LAST SECTION
close(con)

datalist

# $Query1
# [1] "result1" "result2" "result3"

# $Query2
# [1] "result1" "result2" "result3" "result4" "result5"

# $Query3
# [1] "result1" "result2" "result3" "result4"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very elegant but assuming your data is a vector called `data` AND you have something unique to split on (here I used "q") you could do something like this to split it into list items:

```
index <- c(grep("^q", data), length(data)+1)
reps <- c()
for (i in 1:(length(index)-1)) reps <- append(reps, rep(i, index[i+1]-index[i]))
split(data, reps)
```

Alternatively, if your delimiter is a space between query-result blocks, you could read it in with `readLines` and use `grep("^$", data)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your help and suggesting the readLine function (I had no idea it existed).The above codes didn't really generate the output that I was hoping for, however, I was able to modify your codes to write on of my own which worked. I am new to R and coding in general so its probably not the most sophisticated code but it got the job done. Here it is:

```
con<- file("blast5.txt", open = "r")
## Calculate rows and column needed
l<-0; w<-0; i<-0
while (length(line <- readLines(con, n=1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {
if (grepl("Query", line)==TRUE){
l=l+1
if (i>w){
  w<-i
}
i<-0
  }
  else if (grepl(">", line)==TRUE){  # COUNT RESULTS UNDER EACH QUERY
i<-i+1
  }
}
# Make an empty array to store the data
blast<- array(NA,c(l,w+1))
close(con)
i<- 0; j<-1
con<- file("blast5.txt", open = "r")
while (length(line <- readLines(con, n=1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {

  if (grepl("Query", line)==TRUE){
    i=i+1
    j<-1
    blast[i,1] <- line           #STORE QUERY NAME IN FIRST COLUMN
  }
  else if (grepl(">", line)==TRUE){
     j<-j+1
     blast[i,j]<- line           #STORE RESULTS IN SEPARATE COLUMNS 
  }
}
close(con)
```